# How to use ogr2ogr and sql in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I'm having trouble getting sqlite dialect to work with ogrinfo/ogr2ogr in Python.

I'm able to use ogr2ogr/ogrinfo functions in Python by using the Python ports found here -

http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/samples.

I import that script into my script and pass parameters via `sys.argv = []`.

But when I try to use sqlite statements I get errors.

```
sys.argv = ['','myshape_shp','-dialect', 'sqlite', '-sql', "select sqlite_version()"]
```

Returns "ERROR 6: The SQLite driver needs to be compiled to support the SQLite SQL dialect"

My hunch is that since I'm using this python port, it doesn't have sqlite functionality bundled in with it?

This does work if I run the same command through the OSGeo Shell.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me when I run the script from OSGeo4W shell

```
c:\temp\ogrinfo.py -dialect sqlite -sql "select sqlite_version()"
 dummy.shp
INFO: Open of `dummy.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: None
Feature Count: 1
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
sqlite_version(): String (0.0)
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  sqlite_version() (String) = 3.14.1
```

Do you use the same GDAL version with your own script? The error suggests that you do not but Python finds some GDAL version that is compiled without SQLite.